# Broken RSpec and Cucumber tests and not sure where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber

OK, I don't usually ask questions because I don't like looking like an idiot, however, at this point I no longer care. This is driving me insane!

I have a repo here at:

https://github.com/pgpkeys/journal_app/tree/feature/model_rspecs_modification

My gist of the issue is at: https://gist.github.com/977300

I have a factory created (using factory_girl) which exists in `[Dir[Rails.root] + "/factories/*.rb`. My `spec/support/factories.rb` loads this factory. However when I run `bundle exec rake spec` I'm getting constant errors with show,edit,update, and delete that `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:  Couldn't find Owner without an ID`. I have `let(:owner) 
{ Factory(:owner) }` in my `spec/controllers/owners_controller_spec.rb` file . It also requires  `spec_helper.rb` (even though its already done by rake spec) which points to the `spec/support/*.rb` which is supposed to load `factories/*.rb`.

Comment: have you run a rake db:test:prepare?

Comment: Some advice: Don't worry about looking like an idiot. You'll be a lot more productive if you ask questions when you need help. And questions that are embarrassing to ask may very well be the same questions other people want to ask as well. You'll find the resources you need and other people will, too. In other words, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Did your tests ever run successfully? You have `get 'show'` for instance, that doesn't specify any ID, while your controller expects `params[:id]` to be present.

Comment: The first link you posted is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because of 'database_cleaner' gem which wipes the database every time tests run. Because of this, the database could be empty?